# Threading, Winforms, separating TCP operations from the main window form

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, tcp

In my main window form, I have some TCP/IP stuff going on. I'm currently refactoring so everything is in separate classes. I have these functions separated out (TCP now handled by a class called Communicator), but I just noticed that

```
this.Invoke(PDDelegate, new Object[] { tempstr });
```

this part depends on some infrastructure in the Form class. This is what sets up the delegate for processing data that arrives over the TCP pipe.

I'm tempted to pass in a reference to the main window when I call Communicator.Connect, so I could do

```
window.Invoke(PDDelegate, new Object[] { tempstr });
```

But that just seems like a hack to me. I'm wondering if I should worry about this and figure out how to give this object the ability to handle its own threads, or just pass in the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a better way is to embrace the .NET event model. Have the `Communicator` class implement an event and have the form subscribe to that event. That way, you have a clear separation of duties.

In communicator:

```
public delegate void CommEventHandler(object sender, CommEventArgs e);
public event CommEventHandler CommEvent;
```

And then the Communicator raises CommEvent whenever appropriate.

In the form, create the communicator and subscribe to the event:

```
private Communicator Comm = new Communicator();
Comm.CommEvent += MyCommEventHandler;
```

The form should then call `Invoke` as required if it needs to update the UI.

That model eliminates the need for the Communicator to know anything about Forms.

Comment: Hmm. I'm new to threaded programming, so I'm a bit confused. My thought was to have the Communicator get the data, process it, and send events to let the UI know what had changed. I didn't want the window class to have to do the processing. Maybe I don't need Invoke at all if I do it this way? Was Invoke just to guarantee the data showed up in the UI thread?

Comment: Ok, figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yup, that's a hack, all right.

For socket communication, I recommend a `SynchronizationContext`-based approach. e.g., the [Nito.Async.Sockets](http://nitoasync.codeplex.com/) library uses `SynchronizationContext` to marshal results back to the UI thread, without creating a dependency on Windows Forms.

Alternatively, you could write your own wrappers based on [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609). I think that would be a fine idea, but more complex.

Comment: A bit more complex than I needed, but I'll keep the reference handy!